Interchange of differentiation and limit
Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges pointwise a.e. on E to $f$. 
If I want to proved that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x),$ could I apply Lebesgue Dominant Convergence Theorem?
My thought is following:
If $\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)$ converges pointwise a.e. to $h(x)$
and
$|\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$, where g is a integrable function over $E$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=\int \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)$ by LDCT.
It yields $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=\int \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)$.
And differentiate both sides, we obtain $\frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} h(x)$.
I'm not sure if my idea is correct. Can someone tell me? Any suggestions or corrections are welcome! Thank you!

What about the classic example of $f_n(x)=x^n$ when $x \in [0,1]$? The limit of the derivatives converges everywhere to $0$ except at $x=1$ where it converges to $1$, but the derivative of the limit doesn't even exist at $1$ because $f_n$ doesn't converge to an everywhere differentiable function. You should apply your reasoning to this example and see where it fails.

Thank you. I will think about it.
